# PHP - decrease a string ID

Tags: php, string

I'm having trouble with decreasing a string ID. This is the case:

```
// given $row[0]['orderid'] = "ORD00389" (varchar)
$nextID = $row[0]['orderid'];
$prevID = $row[0]['orderid'];
$nextID++; // echo 'ORD00390'
$prevID--; // echo 'ORD00388'
```

What I learned so far is this lovely paragraph:

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations
>   on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a =
>   'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into
>   '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that
>   character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so
>   only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported.
>   Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the
>   original string is unchanged.

Is there any efficient way (built-in function) to decrease that string in PHP?

Comment: i think you should use a regular expression to get the numbers out.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think Galen got it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it ends in ORD every time you can get rid of the ORD, subtract 1, then put it back together.

```
$id_num = intval( str_replace( 'ORD', '', $str ) );
$nextID = 'ORD' . ($id_num+1);
$prevID = 'ORD' . ($id_num-1);
```

If it doesn't begin with ORD every time you could replace all non digits

```
$id_num = intval( preg_replace( '~\D~', '', $str ) );
```

Comment: Or `$id_num = intval ( substr( $prevID, 3 ) );`

Comment: Though I expected a built-in function in PHP but this is great enough ;)